# "Cycle detected: the type b cannot extend/implement itself or one of its own member types" error

Tags: java

The following sample as given below I have 2 interfaces a and b:

```
interface a { void x();}
interface b extends a {void y();}
```

Now I implement  the above interfaces as class i and j.

```
class i implements a{
    void x(){
        //Some code;
    }
}

class j extends i implements b{
    void y(){
        //Some code;
    }
}
```

While compiling Class j I am getting an error "Cycle detected: the type b cannot extend/implement itself or one of its own member types". Can anyone please help me understand the problem.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Your code compiles (if `x` and `y` are made `public`). What IDE are you using?

Comment: The error is that methods x() and y() in classes i and j are not public. The compiler error message is misleading. Which version of Java are you using?

Comment: I am using eclipse ide and jdk 7

Comment: Also kindly note that a and b are in one package while i and j are in another package

Comment: what would be the names of the corresponding (.java) files?

Comment: @xerx593 the interfaces `a` and `b` are stored as a.java and b.java respectively and classes `i` and `j` are stored as i.java and j.java files respectively.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me as if the error is caused by your declaration of class "j" by extending "i" while also implementing "b" which are both children of interface "a".

The effect your producing is as such:
"j extends i" makes "j" an instance of "a" by inheritance;
"j implements b" makes "a" an instance of "b" by inheritance when b is an instance of "a".
Hence your cycle.